# Google analytics event inside Leaflet popup link

Tags: google-analytics, leaflet

I'm looking to include a google analytics event tracker inside my links of a popup on a leaflet map.

Here's what I'm trying now (note the onlick portion of the a tags):

```
    var League = L.featureGroup([
      L.marker([36, -76], {icon: icon}).bindPopup("<center><img src='imgs/K.jpg' alt='Red dot' width = 200/></center></br><table><tr><td>Team</td><td>K</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>Level 1</td></tr><tr><td>League</td><td><a href='http://example.com' onclick=\"captureOutboundLink('http://example.com'); return true;\" target='_blank';>League 1</a></td></tr></table>"), 
      L.marker([36, -76], {icon: icon}).bindPopup("<center><img src='imgs/H.jpg' alt='Red dot' width = 200/></center></br><table><tr><td>Team</td><td>H</td></tr><tr><td>Level</td><td>Level 1</td></tr><tr><td>League</td><td><a href='http://example.com' onclick=\"captureOutboundLink('http://example.com'); return true;\" target='_blank';>League 1</a></td></tr></table>")
    ]);
```

Where captureOutboundLink is:

```
var captureOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
```

The map functions fine. URL clicks are opened in a new window as intended, but google analytics isn't picking up the click events (the rest of the site tracking analytics work fine). I suspect it's the javascript inside of javascript stuff going on here, but I'm not sure what to do next. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ...and what's the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of `captureOutboundLink`?

Comment: Look at the documentation [handling_timeouts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#handling_timeouts) because some events may not be triggered with greater complexity. I tested your solution and it is counted. Remember that it's best to launch the browser window in incognito mode.